# Microsoft Graph - Send message on MS teams on behalf of a user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is there a way to send a message on behalf of a user either in private chat or channel. In my case, the admin gives both application and delegated permission for the app. When the admin is part of the chat/channel, the messages are delivered correctly using MS Graph API but when the chat happens between 2 other signed-in users where the admin is not involved, I am not able to send the message as any of the user. I get UnknownError/Unauthorized since the token which is generated is related to admin user.

If we cannot send a message on behalf of a user using MS Graph is there any other way to achieve this. Can MS Bot take care of this scenario? Will each user have to install the bot so that it can send the message even if the Bot is not part of the conversation?

Comment: Hi@aikadakh. How did you solve this problem finally?

Answer (score 0):

> If we cannot send a message on behalf of a user using MS Graph is
> there any other way to achieve this.

You can [send chat message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) using Graph APIs. To send message on behalf of a user, your app must get consent from each individual users. Application permission is currently not supported.

> Will each user have to install the bot so that it can send the message
> even if the Bot is not part of the conversation?

It's a good idea to build Bot and send notifications instead of sending it from one of the user's account. You can use [Proactive message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) to send message. In order to send message, your Bot needs to be installed for each user.

Could you please elaborate more on scenario? Are you looking for something similar to [Company Communicator](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-company-communicator-app)?

Comment: Getting individual permission for each user might not be scalable. Is there a plan for application permission support?
For Bot, does the bot need to be part of a conversation for it to reply or can it reply to a 1:1 private chat message. I believe, MS graph has a capability to install the app for each user.
What we are looking to build is a scanning service which scans users messages both in 1:1 chat and channel and replies in case the content is inappropriate/against policy.

Comment: We have plans for application permission for sending message, but do not have an ETA to share. You can install the app in personal scope. You can use [Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) for /chats/allMessages -- all chat messages in organization and then notify user in 1:1 using bot.

Comment: The first link is now a 404.

Comment: please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)?